# Web services deployment in IBM Web sphere

Tags: websphere, spring-ws

Good Morning all,
I have problem while deploying my web app in IBM WAS.
I have spring ws and during the deployment, I get the below error,

```
Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create message factory for SOAP: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factorycom.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory
at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:145)
```

I have packaged the saaj-api 1.3 and saaj impl 1.3 jars in my application and i can see them in the lib folder.
I have set the class loading properties in the WAS to parent last.
Any clue or Where am I going wrong?

I'm using WAS version 7.0.0.11

Comment: it seems like a bug http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM19608

Comment: yes. I forgot to update the workaround I did to solve this issue. Added a manifest entry to get through this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this entry to the MANIFEST file to solve this issue,

DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true

Hope this helps some one.